# make an arrow (sign) in google maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm using google maps in my website. But I have a problem -- the maps takes the X and Y from the database and the maps show without any sign in the place like this

[image]

I want to add a sign or arrow in the maps like this

[image]

How do I do this?

The code Is

```js
< script >
  function initialize() {
    var mapProp = {

      center: new google.maps.LatLng('.$rows['
        X '].', '.$rows['
        Y '].'),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE

    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

  }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

< /script>
```

Comment: it looks like you're trying to inject PHP into the javascript without telling it that it's PHP. Try:
`center: new google.maps.LatLng('<?php echo $rows['X']; ?>', '<?PHP echo $rows['Y']; ?>'),`

Comment: @luke_mclachlan
The problem is the add the sign in the place, if I make just to code JS I don't see the sign :'(

Comment: that's because you're trying to inject php into javascript. won't work in the way you're trying to do it. what  is `$rows['
        Y ']`?

Comment: @luke_mclachlan try this code
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script>
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
  
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(34.683902942879214,-1.8800277035522868),
    zoom:11,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE

  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>';
</body>

</html>

Comment: The word you are looking for is [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a marker, see [the example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.683902942879214, -1.8800277035522868),
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```